# Си указатели на многомерный массив

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

В чем разница в записи (что означает каждая)?

```
void * arr
```

и

```
(int**)ar
```

где `ar` - двумерный массив.

Comment: Приведите код, который хотя бы компилируется. Запись void *arr, где, вы сказали, arr - это двумерный массив, не будет компилироваться.

Comment: Ни первый, ни второй не являются ни массивами, ни "указателями на многомерный массив". Переформулируйте вопрос более осмысленно.

Answer (score 5):

Во-первых, из вашего вопроса не понятно, что вы имеете в виду под записью

```
void * arr
```

Я лишь могу предположить, что вы имеете в виду

```
( void * ) arr
```

Более того, вы используете разные идентификаторы: в первом случае `arr` , а во втором случае - `ar`

Я думаю, что это просто опечатка.

Итак, если у вас объявлен двумерный массив, как, например,

```
int arr[M][N];
```

то запись

```
( void * )arr
```

создает временный объект, который является указателем на первый элемент массива, и который рассматривает память, занимаемую массивом как память неопределенного типа. То есть информация о типе элементов массива утеряна.

Фактически, вы получили просто адрес на некоторую память, занятую некоторым объектом.

Что касается данного приведения типа

```
( int** )arr
```

То оно просто не имеет смысла. Эта запись пытается интерпретировать начало массива как объект, являющийся указателем на тип `int`

То есть более подробно в этом выражении `arr` преобразуется к указателю на свой первый элемент, то есть имеет тип `int ( * )[N]`, И, вот, этот указатель (можно сказать, указатель на строку массива) рассматривается (реинтерпретируется) как указатель на указатель на тип `int`.

Это могло бы иметь смысл, если бы, например, размер `int` соответствовал бы размеру `int *`, то есть если бы имело место равенство

```
sizeof( int ) == sizeof( int * )
```

что зависит от платформы, где запускается код, и первый элемент массива действительно содержал бы адрес какого-нибудь объекта типа `int`.

Ниже приведен пример, когда это могло бы работать. Я заменил тип `int` у массива на тип `long` потому что на платформе, где я запускал эту демонстрационную программу размер указателя соответствует размеру типу `long`, то есть равно 8 байтам, то есть имеет место равенство

```
sizeof( int * ) == sizeof( long )
```

Вот программа

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int x = 10;
    long arr[1][1] = { { ( long )&x } };

    int **p = ( int ** )arr;

    printf( "%d\n", **p );
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
10
```

Но эта программа, как я уже сказал, не имеет большего смысла, и скорей всего человек, который использовал запись

```
( int** )arr
```

делал это ошибочно, не понимая, что он делает.:)

Обычно такую ошибку допускают те, кто пытается обратиться к двумерному массиву, как к массиву из указателей. Например, когда динамически распределяют "двумерный" массив, который на самом деле является одномерным массивом указателей на первые элементы других динамически распределенных массивов.:) А затем пытаются применить этот подход действительно к двумерным массивам.:)

То есть имеется большая разница между объявлением

```
int arr[M][N];
```

где имя массива в выражениях преобразуется к типу

```
int ( * )[N]
```

И динамически распределенным одномерным массивом массивов следующим образом

```
int **arr = malloc( M * sizeof( int * ) );
for ( int i = 0; i < M; i++ ) arr[i] = malloc( N * sizeof( int ) );
```

Если вы хотите написать функцию, в которую можно было бы передавать оба массива, созданный компилятором и вами распределенный, то следует динамически выделять память под массив следующим образом

```
int ( *arr )[N] = malloc( M * N * sizeof( int ) );
```

В этом случае первый `arr` - это массив, который при передачи в функцию преобразуется к указателю `int ( * )[N]`, а второй `arr` уже является таким указателем.

Вот демонстрационная программа

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define M 2
#define N 3

void f( int ( *arr )[N], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) printf( "%d ", arr[i][j] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}    

int main( void )
{
    int arr[M][N] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };

    int ( *p )[N] = malloc( M * N * sizeof( int ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) p[i][j] = i * N + j + 1;
    }

    f( arr, M );
    printf( "\n" );
    f( p, M );

    free( p );
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 

1 2 3 
4 5 6
```

Что касается присвоения указателю типа `void *` указателя другого типа, то в C и в C++ это можно делать без приведения типов. Вы можете просто записать

```
void *p = arr;
```

Comment: Спасибо за такооой подробный ответ!
А как обращаться к динамически распределенному двумерному массиву без ошибок? : )

Comment: @polosatui_zver Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.

Comment: кстати, кавычки вокруг `int**` появились при неудачной правке вопроса, в оригинале их не было

Comment: @PashaPash  Спасибо. Когда пишешь много текста, то опечатки неизбежны.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow я вообще-то имел ввиду опечатку в вопросе :) ну да ладно.

Comment: спасибо за кучу примеров!
еще вопрос:
выделяю память так:
int **arr = malloc( M * sizeof( int * ) );
for ( int i = 0; i < M; i++ ) arr[i] = malloc( N * sizeof( int ) );

затем for (i=0;i<N; i++){
             for(j=0; j<M; j++){
заполняю arr[i][j] }}

Хочу имеющийся массив передать в функцию, или просто записать прототип функции, в которую передается подобный двумерный массив. 
Объявление типа : int funk_mass(long **arr) будет ошибочным или нет? : )

Comment: @polosatui_zver У вас нет двумерного массива.  Здесь вы выделили одномерный массив из M элементов int **arr = malloc( M * sizeof( int * ) );  А затем выделили M одномерных массивов и адреса первых элементов выделенных массивов присвоили элементам ранее выделенного массива.  Для такой конструкции параметр функции  должен иметь тип int **. А также вы должны указать еще два дополнительных параметра, которые будут содержать размерности, например. int m, int n

Comment: Ясно, спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

Указатель на тип void может указывать на значения любого типа. Однако для выполнения операций над указателем на void либо над указуемым объектом, необходимо явно привести тип указателя к типу, отличному от указателя на void.

Указатель на объект любого типа можно присвоить переменной типа void*, один void* можно присвоить другому void*, пару void* можно сравнивать на равенство и неравенство, и, наконец, void* можно явно преобразовать в указатель на другой тип. Прочие операции могут оказаться опасными, потому что компилятор не знает, на какого сорта объект ссылается указатель на самом деле. Поэтому другие операции вызывают сообщение об ошибке на этапе компиляции. Чтобы воспользоваться void*, необходимо явно преобразовать его в указатель определённого типа.

Comment: т.е. если я хочу преобразовать указатель типа void в тип int,  я могу написать так:
void * ar=(int**)ar?

Comment: @polosatui_zver,  нет. А то, что Вы написали -- `void *ar = (int **)ar;` на самом деле ровным счетом ничего не делает. Фактически содержимое памяти (4 или 8 в зависимости от архитектуры компа), символически адресуемое именем переменной `ar` пересылается на то же место. В результате ничего не изменяется. Если Вы хотите (к примеру, из чистого любопытства) посмотреть, что получится из адреса при его переписывании в переменную типа int, то можно  написать, например `void *ar = "xaxa"; int a = (long)ar; printf("%p %d\n", ar, a);` (по крайней мере для gcc)